# cyclic scrolling in flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

I need to know possibility of Cyclic scrolling.

I have three calendar as a child of FlowLayoutPanel and when ever, current calendar is completely scrolled, i remove that calendar and then load it as last with next month details as last one.

I need to provide all round robin scrolling with 3 calendars.

Code Snippet:

```
Control ctrl = this.FlowLayoutPanel.Controls[0];
this.FlowLayoutPanel.Visible = false;
this.FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
this.FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(ctrl);
this.FlowLayoutPanel.Visible = true;
```

It works but i am have scrollbar update and glitches in UI. Is there any way to resolve it?

There must not be any glitches in UI and ScrollBar update. It needs to be same as before.

is there any better way to achieve it or please tell me the possibility for this?

Comment: Looks like you are removing and adding the control to repaint the data which is probably causing the glitches.  Instead if you capture the ctrl change event you can get rid of the glitches.  The FlowLayoutPanel has limited properties and Events so I normally avoid using.    Instead I usually using a Panel create my own array of panels which gives me a lot more properties.

Comment: @jdweng: How to detect control change? i dont understand.

Comment: What don't you understand?